# How to call a method using annotations in java?

Tags: java, annotations

I am creating a custom annotation. I want to invoke a method or do some functionalities wherever I apply that annotation. Suppose I create an annotation like `@info(message="Invoking xyz method")`. Wherever the annotation is to be applied the message will be printed on the console.

Comment: can you show an example

Comment: there are several options. AOP, validation, ...

Comment: Could you please provide an example of some methods with the annotation and your expected output?

Comment: I would guess you want the retention to `RUNTIME` since you don't mention it.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 4):

This is a very good use case for AspectJ. A simple implementation would be the following:

The aspect file (defines the behavior to execute, customized by the annotation):

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Before("execution(@com.example.demo.aspect.Info * *(..)) && @annotation(info)")
    public void before(JoinPoint joinPoint, Info info) {
        logger.info(info.value()); // simply print the message from the annotation
    }
}
```

The annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Info {
    String value();
}
```

Using the annotation:

```
@Info("Calling my method here...")
public void myMethod() {
    // your regular business logic
}
```

The above code works pretty much plug-and-play for a Spring Boot enabled application with the spring-aop and aspectjweaver Maven dependencies. For a non-Spring application, you can look into pure AspectJ quickstart docs such as those from https://www.baeldung.com/aspectj